# Oracle Week Number From Date ISO Week But From December 1

Tags: oracle, date

Ok, I've had a query that has been working fine that calculates the week number from December 1 (the start of our Sales Fiscal Year).

Now the requirements have changed. I still need to calculate the week number based on the field (Invoice_Date). However, instead of starting to count from December 1 (Dec 1-7, Week 1, etc.) now I need to start counting on the nearest Monday to December 1st. As I understand it, the ISO week is kind of what I'm looking for but it starts January 1. How do I modify this to work from December 1?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can the nearest Monday be before December the 1sr, after it, or either? Might be helpful to show some dates and the week number you expect.

Comment: Yes, nearest Monday could be before December 1st. I am trying to compare the same number of 'Invoice Dates' over the course of the year. I need the fiscal week to ALWAYS reflect Monday-Sunday. In FY2015 Week 1 would be Dec1-7 but in FY2016 Week 1 would be Nov30-Dec6. My data has the invoice date for each transaction. I want to calculate the 'FW' (Fiscal Week) in my query so if I do a report comparing YTD week 50 of this year to YTD week 50 of last year I am ALWAYS dealing with the same number of Mondays, same number of Tuesdays, etc. Am I making any sense?

Answer (score 0):

`select next_day(to_date('0112' || to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY'),'ddmmyyyy') - 1, 'MONDAY') dec_mon from dual;` 
gives you first Monday of December current year

Number of week is just `ceil((sysdate - dec_mon)/7)`.

If you want last Monday before 1st Dec you can get it by:

```
select next_day(to_date('2511' || to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY'),'ddmmyyyy') - 1, 'MONDAY') 
from dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

In this proposed solution, I build a "helper table" first, showing the `Monday_from` and `Monday_to` for each fiscal year (in the third CTE, named `ranges`). Then I build a few test dates - I was lazy, I should have used `to_date()` so I can include time-of-day component as well. The join condition in the actual solution (at the end of the code) is written so it works without modification for dates with non-zero "time-of-day" component.

I used the nice feature of Oracle 11.2 which allows us to give column aliases in the declaration of CTEs - otherwise the column aliases would need to be moved inside the respective `SELECT`s. Otherwise the solution should work at least for Oracle 9 and above (I think).

```
with
     y ( dt ) as (
       select add_months(date '2000-12-01', 12 * level )
       from   dual
       connect by level <= 30
     ),
     m ( dt ) as (
       select trunc(dt, 'iw') + case when dt - trunc(dt, 'iw') <= 3 then 0 else 7 end
       from   y       
     ),
     ranges ( monday_from, monday_to ) as (
       select dt, lead(dt) over (order by dt) - 1
       from   m
     ),
     test_dates ( t_date ) as (
       select date '2013-02-23' from dual union all
       select date '2008-12-01' from dual union all
       select date '2008-04-28' from dual union all
       select date '2016-11-29' from dual
     )
select t_date, monday_from, 1 + trunc((t_date - monday_from)/7) as week_no
from   test_dates t inner join ranges r
       on t.t_date >= r.monday_from and t.t_date < r.monday_to
;

T_DATE              MONDAY_FROM            WEEK_NO
------------------- ------------------- ----------
2008-04-28 00:00:00 2007-12-03 00:00:00         22
2008-12-01 00:00:00 2008-12-01 00:00:00          1
2013-02-23 00:00:00 2012-12-03 00:00:00         12
2016-11-29 00:00:00 2016-11-28 00:00:00          1
```

Answer (score 0):

The nearest Monday to any any given date is returned with the following function:

```
NEXT_DAY(some_date-4,'Monday')
```

as shown by this query:

```
with dts(some_date) as (
  select date '2006-12-1' from dual
  union all
  select add_months(some_date,12)
    from dts
   where some_date <= date '2014-12-1'
)
select some_date
     , next_day(some_date-4,'monday') nearest
     , some_date - next_day(some_date-4,'monday') dist
  from dts;

SOME_DATE   NEAREST           DIST
----------- ----------- ----------
01-DEC-2006 04-DEC-2006         -3
01-DEC-2007 03-DEC-2007         -2
01-DEC-2008 01-DEC-2008          0
01-DEC-2009 30-NOV-2009          1
01-DEC-2010 29-NOV-2010          2
01-DEC-2011 28-NOV-2011          3
01-DEC-2012 03-DEC-2012         -2
01-DEC-2013 02-DEC-2013         -1
01-DEC-2014 01-DEC-2014          0
01-DEC-2015 30-NOV-2015          1

 10 rows selected
```